# Div bottom aligned in column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 with a four column layout. Now I have one column with longer text which causes the "buttons" at the end to be not aligned.

[image: the actual output]

The HTML is as follows:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mt-4">
            <div class="col-lg-12 title-1 text-center">
                My Headline
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row py-5">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="https://via.placeholder.com/510x661.png" alt="">
                <div class="text-center title-4 volume">lorem</div>
                <hr>
                <div class="text-center title-2">
                    Just a test
                </div>
                <div class="button-1 text-center title-3">
                        MORE INFOS
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 mt-lg-0 mt-5">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="https://via.placeholder.com/510x661.png" alt="">
                <div class="text-center title-4 volume">lorem</div>
                <hr>
                <div class="text-center title-2">
                    This is longer text which causes the issue
                </div>
                <div class="button-1 text-center title-3">
                        MORE INFOS
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 mt-lg-0 mt-5">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="https://via.placeholder.com/510x661.png" alt="">
                <div class="text-center title-4 volume">lorem</div>
                <hr>
                <div class="text-center title-2">
                        Just a test
                </div>
                <div class="button-1 text-center title-3">
                        MORE INFOS
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 mt-lg-0 mt-5">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="https://via.placeholder.com/510x661.png" alt="">
                <div class="text-center title-4 volume">lorem</div>
                <hr>
                <div class="text-center title-2">
                        Just a test
                </div>
                <div class="button-1 text-center title-3 align-self-end">
                    MORE INFOS
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So what can I do to make the "buttons" of all columns aligned?

Comment: What do you want to do with the overflowing text ?

Comment: you can make the cols flex and then just add flex-grow:1; to the title-2 div: https://www.bootply.com/0ubMQ6rCnG not sure if this will work in ie or safari though as I know they have problems with nested flexboxes

Comment: @sebseb24 Not sure if I understand correctly, but the text should stay as is. Just the buttons of the other columns should move down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the columns flexbox (d-flex flex-column), and then use `mt-auto` to push the buttons to the bottom...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-4">
        <div class="col-lg-12 title-1 text-center">
            My Headline
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row py-5 border">
        <div class="col-lg-3 d-flex flex-column">
            <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="https://via.placeholder.com/510x661.png" alt="">
            <div class="text-center title-4 volume">lorem</div>
            <hr>
            <div class="text-center title-2">
                Just a test
            </div>
            <div class="button-1 text-center title-3 mt-auto">
                    MORE INFOS
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 mt-lg-0 mt-5  d-flex flex-column">
            <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="https://via.placeholder.com/510x661.png" alt="">
            <div class="text-center title-4 volume">lorem</div>
            <hr>
            <div class="text-center title-2">
                This is longer text which causes the issue
            </div>
            <div class="button-1 text-center title-3 mt-auto">
                    MORE INFOS
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 mt-lg-0 mt-5  d-flex flex-column">
            <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="https://via.placeholder.com/510x661.png" alt="">
            <div class="text-center title-4 volume">lorem</div>
            <hr>
            <div class="text-center title-2">
                    Just a test
            </div>
            <div class="button-1 text-center title-3 mt-auto">
                    MORE INFOS
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 mt-lg-0 mt-5  d-flex flex-column ">
            <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="https://via.placeholder.com/510x661.png" alt="">
            <div class="text-center title-4 volume">lorem</div>
            <hr>
            <div class="text-center title-2">
                    Just a test
            </div>
            <div class="button-1 text-center title-3  mt-auto">
                MORE INFOS
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/go/B1vKo06A3i

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1: flexbox with column flow and use margin: auto to push the button

That's the answer @Zim posted (he's fast!)

#### Option 2: with text-overflow

Another option without flexbox is to style the text-overflow on the text instead. You can use `text-overflow` on your `title-2` class to ensure the title would be just 1 line.

#### CSS

```
.title-2 {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

#### Result

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/261632/